# E2197 constant object cannot be passed as a var parameter

Tags: delphi

i have 2 forms connected Q1_u and clsPlayer, but as soon as i connect the two it throws error 2197

```
program Q1_p;
uses


 Forms,
  Q1_u in 'Q1_u.pas' {Form1},
clsPlayer in 'clsPlayer.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin

Application.Initialize;
 Application.CreateForm(Q1_u.TForm1, clsPlayer.TclsPlayer);
 Application.Run;
End.
```

Comment: Show a [mcve]. It's easy to guess what is wrong but that won't produce a topic of much value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second argument of `CreateForm` should be a variable that can hold a `TForm` descendant object, not a `TForm` class (as you have provided). Each call to `CreateForm` creates one of the application's auto-create forms: the first argument specifies the form class and the second a variable that will hold a reference to the created instance. So, if you have two auto-generated forms, you need two `CreateForm` calls.

Still, you shouldn't edit your `dpr` file manually, at least not in this case. The IDE does this for you.

Example:

1. Create a new VCL application. Set the main form's name to `MyMainForm` and its colour to `clSkyBlue`.
2. Choose **File/New/VCL Form**. Set the new form's name to `MySecondForm` and its colour to `clMoneyGreen`. The IDE will have made the new form auto-generated; hence, it will have added a new line to your `dpr` file.
3. In the first form, select **File/Use Unit** (Alt+F11). Select the unit with your new form (likely `Unit2.pas`).
4. Drop a `TButton` on your main form, set its `Caption` to `Show second form` and write the following in its `OnClick` handler:

   ```
   procedure TMyMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     MySecondForm.Show;
   end;
   ```
5. If you look at the project source (`dpr` file), you'll see that the IDE had indeed written the code for you:

   ```
   program Project1;

   uses
     Vcl.Forms,
     Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MyMainForm},
     Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {MySecondForm};

   {$R *.res}

   begin
     Application.Initialize;
     Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
     Application.CreateForm(TMyMainForm, MyMainForm);
     Application.CreateForm(TMySecondForm, MySecondForm);
     Application.Run;
   end.
   ```

[image: Screenshot of the two forms]

Notice, however, that in many (most?) cases you don't want auto-generated forms at all, but that is a different story.

Comment: This relies on your, probably correct, guess as to what clsPlayer.TclsPlayer is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed.